# Packaging files in an iOS app for subdirectories of Library

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have a set of XML files that need to go into the app. I'm thinking of making them user-modifiable, too, making them more like templates. In any case, they may change when the app is updated.

According to the iOS [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10) and the data type reference for NSSearchPathDirectory the place to put these files would be Library/Application Support.

The problem is I would only want these files copied in an app install or upgrade. An Xcode build phase didn't seem to cover the situation, although I'm pretty new to this.

The only thing i can really think of is to add a "placeholder file" and only run the install if this file is missing. Then on first install, I can programmatically copy the files from the resource bundle.

If there's a better way, I'd love to know.

Comment: why not save the most recent version into your preference file and compare the saved version with the app version at startup?

Comment: I was shying away from this approach because the files could end up growing both in number and in size

Comment: my preference file has 1000+ entries and is 20kb?A version key is just a string!

Comment: ah, sorry. I misread your suggestion. that would be simple to do, and I might just end up doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who ends up here:

I did end up doing a simple check for existence; depending on how things go I may add either a checksum or a version number to check for modifications.